John 1:1c Out of context, how would a native reader of Koine Greek understand the text?
If a native reader of koine Greek came across the following sample from John 1:1 in isolation and out of context of the scriptures or references to the gospel how would they understand it?

θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος

Would they:

be 100% certain the meaning conveyed was that the word was God?
be 100% certain the meaning conveyed was that the word was divine?
be 100% certain that the meaning conveyed was that the word was a god?
understand the meaning to be possibly one of the above with varying degrees of certainty?
simply need more information to understand?
understand it a sixth way I'm not considering?


When a single verse gives ambiguous meaning, we seek others to fill in the blanks. 1John 1:1-2 does this with explicit detail. While the question is important +1, John 1:1-3 in isolation will never provide clarity.

@Steve, my interest is in understanding what is grammatically possible instead of simply what's the "theologically correct" meaning based on various interested parties' interpretations of the immediate context within the whole of scripture which is then used to filter out what is grammatically possible. This is often done without first acknowledging what is grammatically possible. I just want to understand the answer to that prior to applying interpretive filters. If the text is completely ambiguous outside of interpretive context than that's interesting. If it's not, that's interesting too.

I am Greek, but i am a person who lives in the 21st century, but i have knowledge of that language, cause i am translator. You want me to answer you, or you want me to answer you as a Koine Greek native of that age?

Are you addressing a native who has some knowledge of God or the Scriptures in general?

@Austin If we wanted to say that "the word was divine", we would then say "θεῖος ἦν ὁ λόγος", with an "ι" in the word "θεός", with a change of intonation from “΄” to “~”, and with a change of tone position. So, “θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος” = “the word was a god”; and “θεῖος ἦν ὁ λόγος” = “the word was divine”.

@GeorgeF Thanks for providing that clarification.

The words say (quite clearly) . . . .  'God was the logos'. The arguments multiplying against this simple wording of John the Apostle demonstrate the opposition of the generality of humanity to the concept that John is conveying.

@NigelJ, no arguments here just a simple request for the truth from them that know it.

@Austin - It's a combination of 4 & 5. One certainly needs surrounding context, not to mention a knowledge of the intricacies of Koine Greek grammar, to truly understand John 1:1c. As for even more information? Well, one should have been able to rely on the rest of the NT, unfortunately (for some of us at least) evidence of bias towards "Trinitarianism" in the translation thereof, has been mounting for decades and IMHO can no longer be ignored.

The wording is self explanatory. Very clear and simple words leading to an understanding of the truth.

@NigelJ - Oh, really!!! It's just the most hotly debated verse in the WHOLE Bible .....

@Nigel J Such an isolated phrase cannot be fully understood, just as John describes in 1:1, or 1:1-3, or 1:1-5. Surely, the translation is (as I understood it yesterday, to give you an idea of how clueless I am), "God was the Word." But again, "θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος" seems to make no sense to someone who has nothing to do with the Scriptures or something else talking about God, or because of the lack of the conjunction "καί" before "god". As well as, "ἦν", where it gives a past tense meaning to the status of the word as god. So the phrase cannot be isolated to fully understand John's meaning.

When the Father comes, he shall explain it to you.

While I'm still not quite sure where you are coming from, your question - not to mention your commenting - I find merit worthy and certainly does not deserve 2 downvotes. You now have your 4th upvote. Sorry for the delay.

@OldeEnglish Thx. As I explained above in the comments, I just want to explore what are the grammatical possibilities with the phrase θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος prior to everyone applying their theological interpretive filters. This isn't meant to settle the case. It's very hard for me to ask on this site a question about possible legitimate interpretations based on grammar alone without people foreclosing on those possibilities based on theology without first acknowledging their grammatical legitimacy. We're often just too theologically sensitive for a simple academic discussion purely about grammar.

When I said ... still not sure where you are coming from ... I had been wondering if you were coming from a trinitarian mentality or non-trinitarian. That's all. It would seem that you are of the latter, which is my stance also, as I have already made known in my own comments. My own posts with regard to John's prologue are not without grammatical legitimacy explanations.

@OldeEnglish, I'm sure you don't feel otherwise, but I don't think it should matter where I'm coming from. Either it's a good question or it's not or it's a good answer or it's not. I think too many people (not you specifically) judge questions and answers based on where they think people are coming from.

Only too true, unfortunately.

Fascinating discussion about the Greek language. I find the 'out of context' on purpose question here on this site a clear Achilles heel for this particular StackExchange group called 'Biblical Hermeneutics'. Within continued isolation of the words in John 1 (or anywhere else, really), any verse in John 1 can be proven to show all kinds of teaching, including Christian Perfectionism or maybe some bizarre understandings of the nature of Jesus before time. But that aside, I'm trying to give this my best shot and understand what this particular question is about. What is this about?

As an Alexandrian familiar with Greek Koine grammar after the Jesus age
Let's say I was a speaker of the koine Greek tongue (i.e. I knew syntax and grammar), and I was living in Alexandria of Egypt, and I saw this passage, regardless of whether I was religious or atheist, and I was seeing it for the first time, my mind would go straight to the fact that: “the word was a god”. Because the subject of the sentence here is "the word", the verb is "was", and the predicate is "god".
As a Jew of Palestine
If I were religious, and lived in Palestine, and was a Jew, indoctrinated under the traditions and customs of Moses, then I might agree with Mr. Perry Webb.
As a Christian having knowledge of the tradition and history and Scriptures of the OT, after 100-150 AD.
Again, if I lived after the time of Christ in 100-150 AD (I don't think it matters much where I lived) and was one of the Christians, I think I would immediately understand that it refers to the Jesus Christ of whom John makes reference. “The Word was God” (one of the persons of the Triune God).
As unchurched or uninformed with the history and tradition of the Law of Moses.
Someone who had knowledge of Greek and perhaps history (note: without the philosophers' history, as Heraclitus, etc), or was Greek, but without any of biblical knowledge, and no patristic tradition or Moses tradition (OT), would interpret the phrase with the emphasis on "god". So the meaning in English is that "the word was a god", as a possible god, or as an allegorical expression, i.e. that "the word" as an expression of speech, or word of command, or word of proverb, or word of oracle, or education, or instruction, or myth, or phrase, or verbal skill, or the spoken word in general.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The OP asks, “If a native reader of koine Greek came across the following sample from John 1:1 in isolation and out of context of the scriptures or references to the gospel how would they understand it?”
Would they be 100% certain the meaning conveyed was that the word was God?
This question is based on the use of capitalization to indicate proper nouns. But the Greek was written in all capital letters (An Introduction to the Biblical Greek Alphabet). If the question is whether θεὸς is a proper noun, then more information is needed for the reader to arrive at such a conclusion.
Would they be 100% certain the meaning conveyed was that the word was divine?
The word θεὸς is a noun, whereas “divine” is an adjective. The only reference I could find that includes divine as one of the definitions of θεὸς is the LSJ, which cites classical Greek examples where the word θεὸς is used as an adjective meaning divine, and even then only in the context of comparative statements (Liddell-Scott-Jones Strong’s 2316).
Would they be 100% certain that the meaning conveyed was that the word was a god? Would they understand it a sixth way I'm not considering?
The preverbal predicate nominative construction makes it less likely that θεὸς is indefinite (Wallace, The Basics of New Testament Syntax, pp. 114-118). If the author wanted to write it so that the reader would be more likely to understand θεὸς as indefinite, a better way would be to place it after the verb. In any case, context should always guide how an anarthrous noun should be understood. Without more information, it is difficult to say whether a predicate nominative is definite, qualitative, or indefinite.
John 1:1c
θεὸς    ἦν    ὁ     λόγος
GOD     IS   THE    WORD

It is important to note, however, that there are no indefinite articles in the original Greek. Without an indefinite marker, understanding is something that must be negotiated between the author and the reader either through shared knowledge and experience or context. Imagine the scenario where you did not have the use of indefinite articles in English. Then consider this response to a question: “Teacher is in the classroom.”
Based on the wording alone, we cannot tell whether the subject is definite or indefinite. If the speaker were a student responding to the question “Where is our teacher?”, then we would know that the subject is definite. If the speaker were responding to the question “Where does [a] teacher work?”, then the subject is likely to be indefinite.
Consider another example where someone says, “I am teacher.” If the person were answering the question “How would you describe yourself?”, we would know that the predicate is qualitative. If, on the other hand, the speaker were responding to a group query, “I need to know if there are teachers here”, then we could say that the predicate is more indefinite than qualitative. Granted that in this example, there is not a lot of difference between the two.
The person could be describing himself via the concept of “teacher.” Or he could be saying that he is one among those who fall under the category of teachers. It would be hard to parse between qualitative and indefinite in this case. But unlike “teacher,” the meaning of a word like θεὸς is heavily dependent on context and culture. In reality, it could vary from person to person depending on their personal understanding and experience of θεὸς. In such cases, there may well be a difference between qualitative and indefinite.
In reality, language does not exist in a vacuum. Even if we set aside the context of Scripture, monotheistic and polytheistic beliefs were already established at the time Koine Greek was in use, and the reader would have had to navigate the meaning of θεὸς within that socio-cultural context. If a reader viewed Jn 1:1c through a polytheistic lens, θεὸς may have possibilities of meaning that a monotheistic lens would not allow for. The reverse is also too.
Not for the sake of context but for grammatical purposes only, consider the quotation in John 10:33. Keeping in mind the speakers’ point of view, note that both “man” and “God” are anarthrous. What did the speakers mean by “God” when they were making this charge against Jesus?
John 10:33 NKJV

The Jews answered Him, saying, “For a good work we do not stone You,
but for blasphemy, and because You, being a Man, make Yourself God.”

Would they understand the meaning to be possibly one of the above with varying degrees of certainty? Would they simply need more information to understand?
As noted above, the preverbal predicate nominative construction makes it unlikely for θεὸς to be indefinite. As it is written, θεὸς is likely qualitative but possibly definite or, if I may add, even monadic. More information is needed for the reader to know which meaning the author intends.
Daniel Wallace, The Basics of New Testament Syntax, p. 117

The presumption, therefore, when one faces an anarthrous preverbal PN
[predicate nominative] is that it will be qualitative unless there are
contextual or other considerations suggesting that it is definite or,
less likely, indefinite.


@Austin This response reflects my perspective as someone who is bilingual and whose native language, like Koine Greek, does not use indefinite articles, especially in reference to individuals.

Please correct me if i'm wrong, but wouldn't either a qualitative  or indefinite noun still receive the indefinite article where the noun is a discrete thing as opposed to a substance. For example if the noun was a substance qualitatively you might say "that thing is water." But if the noun was a discrete thing you'd say "that thing is a dog." Likewise if it was indefinite but a substance you might say, "In the room was water," but if discrete and indefinite you might say in the room was a dog. I think the word god is discrete and would use an indefinite article if not definite in English

Just to be clear the above is regarding translating indefinite or qualitative into English even if the original language doesn't use the indefinite article.

@Austin I used the word qualitative, which is what Wallace used, but perhaps conceptual is better. Any noun can reference a concept. Even the word dog can be used to reference people who have characteristics that are associated with our conception of “dog.” When we say that a person is a dog, we do not really mean it in an indefinite sense. What we mean is that they have the characteristics of “dog.” We are using the word dog in a qualitative sense.

Exactly. The use of the term "qualitative" covers your conceptual example. But look. Notice you used an indefinite article in your example of a qualitative noun. So would you agree that the indefinite article is usually used in English for both qualitative and indefinite uses of a noun when that noun represents a discrete entity like a dog or a box or a fish, when there are no other modifiers of that noun?

@Austin When I tried to understand Jn 1:1c through the lens of the English language, I too struggled with how it should be translated. The difficulty lies in trying to force conventions that exist only in English onto the Greek. What I like about your question is that it seeks to know how someone who is fluent in Koine Greek would understand Jn 1:1c. It was only when I took off my English hat, so to speak, could I think about the phrase more clearly.

Excellent perspective. If a language lacks a specific word, in this case the indefinite article, those who use the language are still accustomed to expressing themselves intelligibly. No one then would think in terms of an "indefinite" theos since theos is inherently personal or of something or both. Poseidon was not "a" theos, he presided over seas, storms, earthquakes, horses. The inability to "indefinitize" God is a consequence of the definition of theos at the time. It is wrong to see the English "a god" as a singular indefinite. It's a collective plural of all who are not God.

@Revelation Lad Given the close association between language and cognition, at first I grappled with this question: If a language has no indefinite article, does that mean the concept does not exist? My examples tried to show that while it’s not represented in the syntax and while the speaker may not even be conscious of it, the concept does exist. It is just conveyed in other ways.

@Revelation Lad Because an anarthrous noun is undifferentiated, it is a versatile tool for writing but can be ambiguous without context. As I was pondering this question, my mind kept turning to the broader context of John’s gospel and what he would ultimately have us understand by θεὸς in Jn 1:1c.

On my first read of your answer here, I wasn't entirely accepting of same, but having read it a couple of times more and then after regarding subsequent comments, it's now an upvote from me. For what it's worth my basic stance on this is given in one sentence, in comment under George's 2nd answer. I have, however, given fuller answers to similar Q's, the links to which I gave to George when commenting under both his 1st and 2nd answers.

@Nhi, I see. I think to really  complete the assignment one must put the English hat back on to now faithfully translate what is learned by putting on the Greek hat into how that thought would be expressed in English. It wouldn't be forcing English conventions onto Greek, but using proper English to best convey what the thought is in Greek to those who speak and think in English. The problem I see is when trying to convey Greek thought in English, forcing the Greek conventions onto English can really botch up what is meant to be conveyed in English.

@Austin (Sorry for the late reply) I agree to a certain extent. Without context, we cannot translate Jn 1:1c properly, but if we consider context and the strict monotheism that underlies John's gospel and the rest of Scripture, there is little to justify translating θεὸς as "a god." Whatever our differences may be, your question helps to illustrate the difficulties and risks of interpreting meaning without context.

@Nhi, Hi. Just saw ur latest edits & haven't been responding to them, but based on your last comment you essentially won't translate it properly into English out of context of scripture because of how you think it should be translated properly in context of scripture, thus nullifying the question I asked. Regarding your latest edit, it is false that the categorical indefinite article, in English, necessarily implies plurality. For example, in Eden, an angel could ask what kind of being is Adam? Another could reply "Adam is a man", without contradicting the follow-up that "he is the only man".

@Nhi, it seems the real problem is that "a god" allows for the consideration of plurality and that such allowance is not allowed.

@Austin My point wasn't to push any one translation but to show the problems of translating Jn 1:1c with an indefinite article. I understand the issues you raise, but we have veered into the area of translation, which is beyond the scope of the original question. I have edited my response once again to keep the focus more on the original query.

I'm going to say that the question is moot. θεὸς is established as a proper noun in the first clause, which directly impacts its usage in the third clause. If it were wholly isolated, it would not be incorrect to apply an indirect article. θεὸς, in and of itself, is not a proper noun. It is used in relation to idols, and even Satan. But when θεὸς is expressed with the definite article identifying it as a proper noun, it retains that usage in subsequent related clauses, even in the anarthrous form.

And combine this with predicate nominatives being anarthrous gives a reason for anarthrous.

@Perry Webb, Exactly.

Thanks for answering the question as written even though you object to it as moot overall.

I will say I think the moot argument is weakened somewhat by the fact that The Word is with "The God." Because two agents are introduced in 1:1a, it isn't obvious that the anarthrous theos that the Word was is necessarily the same as the arthrous theos that the Word was with. It seems natural (without monotheistic theological considerations) to consider them separate beings without more information, than just John 1:1, directly saying they're the same theos (again unless you assume strict monotheism). This is why I asked for answers without those considerations which you did provide. Thx again

@Austin. Apologies if this comes across as condescending. It is not intended to. Anarthrous means that the noun does not have a definite article. In the beginning was the Word (articulated), and the Word was with [the] God (articulated), and the Word was God (anarthrous). The reason I say the question is moot is that the third clause in isolation has a different meaning than it does in its full context. But I did answer this question more thoroughly elsewhere. It might be worth a read for you: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/94155/65881

@AFrazier, I don't find it condescending at all. Again I appreciate your answer even if I believe you need more information than just John 1:1 to confirm that the god the Word was is the same as The God the Word was with in the beginning. Thanks again.

My other answer was not only not complete, but it was not well-founded, not even to some extent correct, but completely wrong. That is why I am writing another response.
To begin with, we may say that we cannot separate a phrase or words from the syntax by which John conveyed its essential meaning, because it is not possible for that particular severed phrase to fit the whole meaning. And because there is a difference of opinion, it is better to give a detailed account.
Briefly, in free translation, the meaning is this
1:1-5: 1 The Word existed in the beginning, and the Word existed toward God's presence [Father's (or maybe, in the God office {of rank})], and God was the Word. 2 He existed toward God's presence [Father's (or maybe, in the God office {of rank})] from the beginning. 3 All things were made through Him, and without Him nothing was made that has been made. 4 In him was the life, and the life was the light of men.5 And the light shines in the darkness, and darkness did not prevail against it.
1:9-18: 9 It was the true light, which shines on every man coming into the world. 10 He was in the world, and the world through him has made, and the world did not recognize him (or another possible translation of "ἔγνω": "and the world regarded him as a stranger to it"); 11 He came to his own, and his own did not accept him (or did not accept him in their heart). 12 But those who accepted him, to them he gave authority to become childrens of God, to those who believe in his name, 13 who were born, not of bloods (probably meaning different generation of two opposite sexes), nor of carnal desire, nor of the will (or desire) of a man, but of God.
1:14-18: And the Word became flesh and dwelt among us, and we watched him, beholding his glory, glory as of the only begotten, from the Father, full of grace and truth. 15 John testifies of him, and has cried out, saying: "it was he, for whom I said, 'He who comes after me, He existed before me, for he was prior to me. 16 For we have all received by his fullness, and grace upon grace: 17 For the Law was given through Moses; grace and truth were given through Jesus Christ. 18 God has never been seen to anyone; the only begotten God who is in the presence of the Father, he has made him known.
Looking through the first verse of the original text, with the phrase the questioner mentions cut out, and below it the translation without capital letters, and still further down in capital letters
1,1: ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ λόγος, καὶ ὁ λόγος ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν, καὶ [θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος].
1,1: the word existed in the beginning, and the word existed toward God presence, and [god was the word].
1,1: The Word existed in the beginning, and the Word existed toward God presence, and [God was the Word].
The question that will enter the mind of one who reads it, seeing only this phrase, but having nothing to do with the Law, or with anything referring to God in general —as a knowledgeable of Greek grammar and syntax, and generally disciplined with that language— is this: "what was that “word”? and why is the past tense used with “was”; is it no longer “God”; but also, the grammar and syntax of the sentence, one who spoke the common Greek, knows how to recognize it, and by implication to translate the phrase, plus he can easily understand that it has some preceding or following text, inferring that it is disjunctive.
Plus, John here refers to the Jews, not Gentiles, regardless of the fact that we all reads this text today.
Other translations

There is, of course, another translation version, which emphasizes "god", and which is expressed with admiration, as we would place an exclamation point in the sentence today (the admiration punctuation mark). Such a translation would only be possible if (besides being detached from John's first verse) it referred to a Greek pagan polytheist, who would give to "logos", a divine quality, i.e., by calling him "a god", but quite different from the meaning given by John; i.e, according to the beliefs of an ancient Greek pagan; who, too, may would either give an allegorical meaning to "logos". Anyway, this translation is rendered as follows: "the lóghos was a god"! This translation, however, is completely out of touch with reality, and it is not translated by someone who is a stranger to religious traditions.

Another version, also, but incorrect, could be: "the Word was God". This comes, mainly, from people without having knowledge of the Greek language (like me, where I believed it until recently), because he would not have understood, apparently, the meaning of the syntax of this phrase; thus translating the phrase as follows: "In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.


Analysis of grammar & syntax.
• ἐν ἀρχῇ = prep. ἐν + ἀρχῇ noun > Locative case of time (ancient case), merged in the Dative case (Means the beginning of a creation). Meaning: in the beginning (as initial point; cf. Gen. 1:1 בְּרֵאשִׁית. By the Locative case he emphasizes the existence of the subject, which will be referred below, on the primary starting point).
• ἦν = Past Continious tense of εἰμί, in the 3rd person singular (denotes an existence).
• ὁ λόγος = article + noun, in Nominative case. And here, immediately, a real substance is given to "λόγος", because "existence" precedes it.
• καὶ ὁ λόγος = conj. + art. + λόγος, noun, Nominative case (and the Word. We capitalize it, anyway, for we are referring to a person, because he has an existence, whose name is "Loghos").
• ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν = verb ἦν (real substance) + prep. πρός Acc. case + Acc. case art. τόν + θεόν, Acc. case noun. Here is the verb past tense “existed”, the prep. “toward” which is in Accusative case and indicates destination (or maybe, purpose), the art. which is connected with the preposition, and "God", implying the position that the Word had. Meaning: He existed toward God presence (or maybe, in the God office [of rank]).
• καὶ θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος = conj. καί + θεός, noun + ἦν verb “existed” + ὁ λόγος, art. with noun in Nominative case “the Word” (and the Word existed as God, but more specifically, i.e., and God was the Word)
Translation
The Word existed in the beginning, and the Word existed toward God presence [Father's (or maybe, in the God office)], and God was the Word.
Here is some evidence for the Word's status as God.
(The numbering order of the verses is according to the Septuagint of Rahlfs-Hanhart edition)
Here is the website that provides interlinear information/translation of the Rahlfs edition of LXX: https://www.biblebento.com/index.html?lxx1i&10.1.1
If you notice throughout the Scriptures, the angel/Jesus (see LXX with comparison Gen 32:4) is the person/face-God; try to pay attention to what is said in Gen 16:7-14, 17:1,22, 18:1-5,9-33; 28:10-22 [see for the last one before 35:1; as for seeing the Father cf. Jn. 1:18; 6:46]; 32:23-33 [for this see also Hosea 12:4-5]; 35:9-15 Ex. 3:1 - 4:17 [see also Act. 7:30-38]; 5:22 - 6:13; Deut. 5:22-27 [see also Act. 7:38,53,55-56,59; Jn. 1:18; 6:46]; Josh. 5:13 - 6:5; Judges 2:1-5; 6:11-27 also see. 6:2 - 12:1 the paragraph changes, and 12:43 - 13:3 ff. as well as Lev. paragraph changes, Num. partly, in almost all of Deut. up to ch. 30 God speaks to Moses and then Moses conveys them to the people of Israel; see also Josh. Psalm 2:7; 44:7-8; 109 [compare Matt. 22:41-46; Luke 20:41-44]; Prov. 8; 30:30; Job 38; Wis. Sol. 7:15-30; 9; Wis. Sirach 1; 24; Isa. 8:23b - 9:6; 50:1 - 54:10; 59:13 - 62:5,11-12,7-9,11-18 [see also Act. 8:30-35]; Mic. 5:1-4a; Zech. 12:8-10; Ezek. 34:16-31 [compare with John 10:11-16 & Matt. 25:31-46]; Isa. 7:14 & Matt. 1:23 [Emmanuel = God (is) with us]; Matt. 3:3b [& Isa. 40:3-5]; 7:21-23; 8:23-27 [& Mark 4:36-41; Luke 8:23-25]; Matt. 23:34-39 [compare with Matt. 21:9b; Luke 19:38; Psalm 117:14-29]; 24:30-31; 25:31; Mark. 6:47-51; 8:2-9; Luke 5:2-9. 1:13-17,43,76; John. 3:13,18,33-35; 4:10,25-26; 5:22,36-44; 6:26-71; 8:12,14,16,18-19,24-25,28,41-43,46-47,56-58; 9:5; 10:30,38; 12:38-41,45; 13:13-14,19-20; 14:6-11 [cf. and Deut. 18:15-19]; 17; 18:36-37; 19:34-37 [see Ex. 12:1-20 preparation for Passover & Zech. 12]; Act. 3:14-15; 7:47-50 [see along with John 1:3; Act. 14:15] 9:3-7 10:36,42; Rom. 2:16; 8:32-34; 9:3-5; 10:9; 14:11 [see also 2:16; Act. 10:42]; 1 Cor. 8:6; Philip. 2:5-11; Col. 1:15-20; Heb. 1; Revel. 1:4,12-19; 2:8,18- 3:14- 4:11.

I have hesitated to say anything further to you re. this Q., particularly as you deigned to view my linked A., to a similar Q., but here you are again. This may indeed be a better answer to the Q., but I feel it is still biased towards trinitarianism, which I, myself, can't abide with. The fact of the matter is, that John saw this second "theos" ... as an anarthrous pre-verbal predicate nominative, to describe the class, or category, to which the subject (the Word) belongs, NOT what he supposedly was.

Here's where you can find another answer of mine to regard:- https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48224/the-text-says-that-the-word-is-in-the-beginning-at-john-11-but-god-is-not-said/48270#48270 ... that is IF you can find the time ...

@GeorgF, your translation of  ἦν πρὸς τὸν θεόν seems a bit wild to me. How do you come to the conclusion that θεόν is a rank or office instead of a kind or type of being? This seems unjustified. Also, how do you go from the word "toward" as a reasonable translation of πρὸς  to the word "in" as if The Word was occupying God instead simply being "towards" or "for" God. Lastly why do you rule out that πρὸς  can mean "with" even in the accusative? In BDAG it states as a possible definition for the accusative: (g.) by, at, near πρός τινα εἶναι be (in company) with someone.

@Austin I adjusted it. I apologize for that

Hi George F, no need to apologize. 1) You still seem to think that God office is at least a legitimate option even if not the answer. I'm genuinely curious why you think θεόν  can be understood in context and in the rules of grammar to be an office instead of a type of being.  2) Why do you rule out "with" as a legitimate option that BDAG includes for the accusative? Again I'm just genuinely curious what your though process is.

@Austin The word "with" is a free translation (though it is not wrong); what the text means, I think, is that the Word was from the beginning of creation alongside the Father (in the presence of the Father [literaly: toward God presence]).

@Austin I also add in brackets the different translation, which, in fact, is not different; because the Word was acting as God, and this preposition, sometimes indicates the purpose (not ever the destination, or relation).

@Austin Examples, as a sample, of the Accusative case indicating purpose can be seen in Ex. 7:1; Ezek. 34:24; Matt. 2:10β (see LXX Greek text)

George, when I took the time to respond to your exasperatingly lengthy A., to the Q: When the earth was formless and void .... I even ended up getting past the exasperation and upvoted same, and thought that you might indeed be worth following. It would now seem, however, that I was mistaken in that assumption. Here we now have, after numerous editing, another truly lengthy and even dubious answer (2nd even), where you have chosen little courtesy to the one who gave you that in kind, when you were just starting out here. It's neither an up or down vote from me. Good luck going forward.

@GeorgeF, Ok. Thanks for sharing.

@GeorgeF - Thanks for the "Chat Room" conversation.

@GeorgeF, you wrote  *"This translation, however, is completely out of touch with reality, and it is not translated by someone who is a stranger to religious traditions"_. Did you mean  "This translation, however, is completely out of touch with reality, and it would be translated by someone who is a stranger to religious traditions"?

@Austin it could not be translated

@GeorgeF, Ok that makes a little more sense and by "could not be translated" you mean it could not properly be translated consistent with John's intentions?

Daniel B Wallace, in his Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics, page 269, says this:

The most likely candidate for Θεὸς is qualitative. This is true both
grammatically (for the largest proportion of pre-verbal anarthrous
predicate nominatives fall into this category) and theologically (both
the theology of the Fourth Gospel and the NT as a whole). There is a
balance between the Word's deity, which was already present in the
beginning (Ἐν ἀρχῇ ... Θεὸς ἦν [1:1], and his humanity, which was
added later (σὰρξ ἐγένετο [1:14]). The grammatical structure of these
two statements mirrors each other; both emphasize the nature of the
Word, rather than his identity. But Θεὸς was his nature from eternity
(hence εἰμί is used), while σὰρξ was added at the incarnation (hence
γίνομαι is used.)

That is, John 1:1c is a qualitative category statement common in Greek logic.  That is, John is saying the Logos is in the unique category of "God".  The rest of the gospel of John appears to continually add and reinforce this point, reaching a climax at the other book-end with John 20:28, as follows:

John 1:18, “…but God the one and only who is at the Father’s side has made him known”
John 5:17, 18, “In his defense, Jesus said, ‘My Father is always at his work to this very day, and I too am working.’  For this reason they tried all the more to kill him; not only was he breaking the Sabbath, but he was calling God his own Father, making him equal to God.”  See also Luke 22:69-71.
John 5:23, “so that all may honor the Son just as they honor the Father. Whoever does not honor the Son does not honor the Father who sent Him.”
John 10:30, “I and the Father are one.”  (Compare Deut 6:4.)
John 20:28, “Thomas said to him, ‘My Lord and my God.’”  (This declares Jesus as ὁ Θεός.)  [Compare this statement with Ps 35:23, “Contend for me, my God and Lord.”  See also V24.]

Thus, there can be little doubt about what John, inspired by the holy Spirit, intended with his introductory statement.

if quality is implied than wouldn't divine or deity be more accurate than god? "God" is generally presented as an agent instead of a quality while divine and deity are more associated with identity of qualities instead of identifying an agent.

@Austin, for me, what you've said here sounds like an etymological debates starter. But since the topic is "God/deity", I'm quite sure it can only end in a state of biases arguing one with another. Though I don't think deity would be more accurate. θεὸς in Psalm 18:30, YLT "God! perfect is His way", — God-as-agent is qualified by perfect-way. θεὸς in Amos 8:9, YLT "An affirmation of the Lord .. have caused darkness on the land", — qualified differently. But Psalm 138:2, YLT "For Thou hast made great Thy saying(λόγιόν) above all Thy name", — states, that 'word' is exclusive quality.

@Austin - I do not suggest that "quality" is implied, but "category".  I will update the answer to reinforce this point.

@Austin There are words to describe divine or deity. For example θεότης. If John meant divine/deity he woukd use θεότης not θεός. The actual composition makes divine/deity (θεότης) impossible.

@Dottad. Thanks, I understand. I ended up giving this a thumbs down as it answer from the perspective of someone familiar with John versus as the question asked from the perspective of someone unfamiliar with scripture. My point was to inquire about the grammar prior to people applying an interpretive filter based on knowledge of John,  scripture or Christian theology.

@RevelationLad, thanks. George F helped confirm the same.

The phrase θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος in English would be God was the Word. In Greek the subject is identified by case, not word order. Since both God and Word are in written as nominative, either could be the subject.
About θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος A.T. Robertson states the article indicates is ὁ λόγος is the subject:

The subject is made plain by the article (ο λογος) and the predicate without it (θεος) just as in John 4:24 πνευμα ο θεος can only mean "God is spirit," not "spirit is God." So in 1 John 4:16 ο θεος αγαπη εστιν can only mean "God is love," not "love is God."

Without any other context, the English equivalent would be Word was God. It would be inappropriate to say the Word because the article was used to identify the subject, not to make Word definite. In all the examples cited,  ο θεος is translated as God, not the God.

Clever answer and counter example, but I think your example is flawed. The word 'god' refers to a discrete being. The word "spirit", though, can refer to a discrete being or the substance or essence of a thing. It's more natural in English to say "the toy is a dog" than to say "the toy is dog" since the word "dog" refers to a discrete thing, but "the toy is wood" makes sense in English since wood can refer its substance. Thus I don't think your "spirit" comparison is valid. The word is god only works in English if g is capitalized, but a capitalized g reading would be unlikely out of context.

First of all, Koine Greek was not a native language.  It was an international language similar today to what some have called pidgin English.  It was not John's spoken language and not native to most of the people reading John's Gospel.  Thus, your question doesn't have a simple answer.
Here's one answer for the first century Jew reading John's Gospel:
https://free.messianicbible.com/feature/beginning-memra/
To the Greek familiar with Greek philosophers, they would see Logos as reason or wisdom, which they saw as the only way people could relate to God.
Basically, your question still leaves you with the same discussion already discussed in Biblical Hermeneutics.

By native I mean native to that time and general region where it was spoken and read (the Roman Empire was not all of the Earth). You mention the Jew reading John's Gospel when I distinctly excluded the contexts of the gospel and scripture in general. Greeks were polytheists and the word logos had multiple meanings in philosophy such that is seems improbable that a common reader would automatically and uniformly relate the term the logos to the monotheistic god implied by the English convention "God," and you provided no evidence to the contrary.

Remember, the polytheists that dominated first century Roman culture called Christians cannibals because of Communion/Eucharist/the Lords Supper.  They didn't have the view I would rely on to interpret Scripture.  John had a Jewish background and many of his initial readers would have similar backgrounds.
