# What does "equality with God" mean, and how can it be "exploited"? Philippians 2:6

Tags: christology, philippians, trinity, attributes-of-god

Philippians 2:5-8 (NRSV):

> 5 Let the same mind be in you that was in Christ Jesus,
> 6 who, though he was in the form of God,
> did not regard **equality with God**
> as something to be **exploited**, 7 but emptied himself,
> taking the form of a slave,
> being born in human likeness. And being found in human form, 8     he humbled himself
> and became obedient to the point of death—
> even death on a cross.

Verse 6 says that Jesus didn't regard his prior "equality with God" as something to be exploited. What does "equality with God" mean in this context, and how can it be "exploited"?

Comment: The translation 'did not count equality with God a thing to be grasped' is an interpretation. The original conveys a different concept, that of equality already being in existence. But being not inappropriate. The ESV interpretation is saying he _was  not equal God_ because _he did not grasp it._

Comment: @NigelJ - I changed it to NRSV

Comment: This question now has two major question in it not just one.  I will update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major parts to this question which I will deal with sequentially.

**A: Equality with God**

The idea of Jesus' equality with God is expressed in various ways in the immediate context and in other places such as:

- Phil 2:6 - Jesus was "in the form of God"
- John 1:1-3 - Jesus was both "with God" and "was God"
- John 5:17, 18, “In his defence, Jesus said, ‘My Father is always at his work to this very day, and I too am working.’  For this reason they tried all the more to kill him; not only was he breaking the Sabbath, but he was calling God his own Father, making him equal to God.”  See also Luke 22:69-71.
- John 5:23, “so that all may honour the Son just as they honour the Father. Whoever does not honour the Son does not honour the Father who sent Him.”
- John 10:30, “I and the Father are one.”  (Compare Deut 6:4.)
- John 20:28, “Thomas said to him, ‘My Lord and my God.’”  (This declares Jesus as ὁ Θεός.)  [Compare this statement with Ps 35:23, “Contend for me, my God and Lord.”  See also V24.]

Note: If we take the corpus of the four Gospels, Matt 1:23 and John 20:28 (& 21:19) we find that they begin and end with clear, unambiguous statements that Jesus is God, more specifically, “The God” = ὁ Θεός.

Ellicott comments as follows:

> The sense [in Phil 2:6] is that, being in the form of God, and therefore having
> equality with God, He set no store on that equality, as a glory to
> Himself, compared with the power of giving salvation to all men, which
> He is pleased to consider a new joy and glory.

Barnes reaches a similar conclusion -

> Thought it not robbery to be equal with God - This passage, also, has
> given occasion to much discussion. Prof. Stuart renders it: "did not
> regard his equality with God as an object of solicitous desire;" that
> is, that though he was of a divine nature or condition, be did not
> eagerly seek to retain his equality with God, but took on him an
> humble condition - even that of a servant.

This idea of Jesus' equality with the Father as God is seen throughout the NT - here is a sample of how the OT takes unique attributes of God and applies them to Jesus.

| Attribute | Old Testament | New Testament |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Creator | Isa 44:24, 45:18 | John 1:3, Col 1:16, 17, Heb 1:2 |
| Savior | Isa 43:3, 11, 45:17, 21 | Matt 1:21; Acts 4:12; 2 Tim 1:10; Tit 1:4, 2:13, 3:6; 2 Pet 1:1, 11 |
| Glory | Isa 42:8, 48:11 | John 17:5, 24 |
| Rock | Isa 44:8; Deut 32:3,4,15; Ps 92:15 | 1 Cor 10:4 |
| "I AM" | Ex 3:13-15; Deut 32:39, Isa 41:4, 43:10, 13, 25, 45:19, 46:4, 48:12, 51:12, 52:6 (LXX) | Matt 14:27, Mark 6:50, Mark 13:6, Luke 21:8, Mark 14:62, Luke 22:70, John 4:26, 6:20, 8:24, 28, 58, 13:9, 18:5-8. |
| Shepherd | Psalm 23:1; Eze 34:11ff | John 10:11-16; Heb 13:20; 1 Peter 2:25, 5:4; Rev 7:17 |
| Bridegroom | Isa 49, 54, Jer 2, Hosea | Mark 2:19, Matt 9:15, Luke 5:34, 35 |
| First & Last | Isa 41:4, 44:6, 48:12 | Rev 1:17, 18, 22:13 |
| Lord of Lords | Deut 10:17, Ps 136:3, 26 | Rev 17:14, 19:16 |
| Lord of All | Deut 10:17, Josh 3:11, 13; Ps 97:5, Zech 4:14, 6:5, Mic 4:13 | Acts 10:36, Rom 10:12, Col 1:15 |
| Seven Eyes of the the LORD | Zech 4:10 (& Zech 3:9) | Rev 5:6 (Lamb) |

**B: The Noun ἁρπαγμός**

The noun ἁρπαγμός (harpagmos) occurs only in Phil 2:6 in all the NT and is never used in the LXX, nor in any other early Christian literature.  Its meaning is debated as is clear from the three basic meanings (and two sub-meanings) in BDAG.  Most other lexicons similarly prevaricate.  The modern version are also very diverse in their translations.

[The cognate verb ἁρπάζω (harpazó) is used frequently is places like John 10:28, 1 Thess 4:17, Rev 12;5, 2 Cor 12:2, 4, with the idea of seizing and stealing or snatching away property, robbing.]

The basic and fundamental meaning is: something that is grasped and snatched away, robbery.  However, as BDAG observes, "which is next to impossible in Phil 2:6 ... the state of being equal with God cannot be equated with the act of robbery."

[Neither UBS5 nor NA28 list any variants in the text of Phil 2:6 and none for this word specifically.]

The modern translations can be classified into several groups:

1. "robbery", eg, KJV, NKJV, DRB, YLT
2. "thing to be grasped" (or similar), eg, NLT, ESV, BSB, BLB, NASB, ASV, ISV, NET, NHEB, Weymouth, etc.
3. "something to be used to his own advantage", or "something to be exploited", or, similar, eg, NIV, NRSV, CSB, HCSB, CEV, GNB, GWT, etc.

As shown above, the NT goes to considerable lengths to portray Jesus as "equal to God" as this very verse makes clear.  Further the following verses (7, 8) also describe Jesus' infinite humiliation by His seven-step descent to the lowest level of humanity:

- emptied himself
- taking human likeness
- the form of a servant
- humbled Himself
- became obedient to death
- even death on a cross

Thus, the force of Phil 2:6 appears to be that Jesus' equality was not something that He would grasp and not let go but was willing to humiliate Himself in the process of the incarnation.  That is, the best rendering of the verse is probably (and surprisingly) given by NLT: "*Though he was God, he did not think of equality with God as something to cling to*."

The pivotal importance of this passage in Phil 2:5-11 cannot be overstated.

- Jesus was God and equal to God before the incarnation
- Jesus humbled Himself during the incarnation
- Jesus was exalted to the highest position after the incarnation.

This simple passage in Phil 2:5-11 simply explains the many "subordination" references such as John 5:19, Matt 26:39 - Jesus voluntarily gave up some of His divine privileges during the incarnation such as omnipresence and omnipotence - He still had them but voluntarily did not use them but depended on the Father at all times during the incarnation.

Comment: I changed the title a little bit, just letting you know in case you might want to update the answer

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator - that is a significant change and almost requires a separate answer

Comment: "If we take the corpus of the four Gospels, Matt 1:23 and John 20:28 (& 21:19) we find that they begin and end with clear, unambiguous statements that Jesus is God" Matthew 1:23 just states 'they will call him Immanuel'. That's not an unambiguous statement IMO. Jesus is God's representative who was sent by God, and so God is with us through his representative, Jesus. Put it another way - I had a childhood friend named Emmanuel. Is that proof that he was God?

Comment: @AnthonyBurg - Jesus is called "Emmanuel = The God with us" (literally from the Greek.)  THAT is a clear statement - and uses the unambiguous title, ho theos as well.

Comment: @Dottard Do you hold then that Isaiah 7:14 is purely prophetic re the Messiah, and didn't apply to a child ('Immanuel') born during the time of King Ahaz?

Comment: Re the translation of the name 'Emmanuel', though, that's entirely ambiguous. It's only by taking a trinitarian lens to it that you think it isn't. Jesus is a representative of The God, yes. He was sent by The God. In that sense, The God is with us.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg - there are two matters about Isa 7:14 - (1) no child is recorded as ever having such a name - See Isa 8:3; (2) even it such a child was born, the NT application clearly extends it to apply to Jesus as the Hebrew Emmanuel is "God with us" but Matthew deliberately upgrades the name to "The God with us".  Thus, the sign given to Ahaz was a prophecy of the coming Messiah.  Lastly note that the LORD, YHWH is called Emmanuel in Isa 8:8, 10.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg - I simply read the Bible as is - Matt 1:23 describes Jesus as "The God with us".  End of story.  It is only you that has raised the topic of the Trinity which I did not have in mind.

Comment: @Dottard Jesus says he's the Son of God. I simply read the Bible as it is, and so Jesus is not God. End of story! But seriously, it is you who are claiming there are clear, unambiguous statements that Jesus is God - how is that not raising the issue of the trinity? I am simply replying to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119834/discussion-between-dottard-and-anthony-burg).

Comment: Re 'no child is recorded having that name', neither did Jesus! Hence his name.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg - I have proved that above - Jesus was God Almighty and inherited the titles and honor due to YHWH according to the NT.

Comment: This entire premise is wrong. The "equality with god" being John 3:35 and John 5:30,  where there is clearly a context to the "equality" - the son exercising authority on behalf of the father and yet the "equality" clearly not being absolute - see Matthew 26:53. This power and yet obedience being the subject of Philippians 2:6. If Jesus had exercised that authority *to his own ends* instead of to the will of the father and submitting to the crucifixion, then there would be *no salvation for us* - '... did not regard equality with God as something to be exploited ...' - *could have* but didn't.

Comment: And btw, even the presentation of the information is flawed : "John 1:1-3 - Jesus was both "with God" and "was God"". Err no. The logos or idea was in the beginning with god. Rookie mistakes leading to silly thinking.

Comment: @davidianwalker - so the "idea" that was "with God" was also God?  Err, No.

Comment: θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγος - theos was the logos. It's not theos was Jesus, obviously. Not only clear from the word "logos" but also clear from John 1:14 where that idea manifested in a man, obviously after John. Jesus is not the logos rather the logos manifest as John is deliberate about, this being the function of the introduction in John 1. To suggest otherwise is to reject John's deliberate progression through this introduction and to also reject the accounts of the conception and birth of Jesus. Derrrr.

Comment: As to θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγο - theos was the logos, a calling to mind of Hebrews 1:14 should help here. Are not all angels ministering spirits sent to serve those who will inherit salvation? An idea echoed throughout the bible. The purpose and function of the elohim was the furtherance of the logos expressed in the beginning in Genesis 3:15,21 etcetera. A process revisited in Abraham and Isaac and so on.

Comment: @davidianwalker - θεὸς ἦν ὁ λόγο does NOT say "God was the word", it DOES say, "The Word was God".  This is rather very basic Greek grammar because logos has the article and theos does not.

Answer (score 1):

My rendering of this is a non-trinitarian one, and relies on a keying to John 1:1, which I understand as (following Moffatt) "The Logos existed in the very beginning, the Logos was with God, the Logos was divine."

https://www.bibliatodo.com/en/the-bible/james-moffatt-new-testament/john-1

So I believe this first part "he was in the form of God" is basically a restatement of John 1:1 - Christ Jesus was with God and divine before his human incarnation.

The second part "did not regard equality with God as something to be exploited" I would translate instead as "thought it not a prize to be grasped at to be equal with God", following Ellicott's preferred translation.

https://biblehub.com/commentaries/ellicott/philippians/2.htm

In other words, although with God, he was willing to 'come down' and take human form and not 'grasp at' staying with God. This leads ultimately to death on the cross (as St. Paul notes) and also perhaps to God forsaken-ness on the cross ("My God, my God, why have you forsaken me?" Matthew 27:46). Whatever the case, it is a difficult row to hoe, but Jesus does it because it is God's will. If even Jesus is willing to come from being with God to death on a cross, so we similarly (continues St. Paul) should be willing to do things that are in accordance with God's will "without complaining or arguing" (Philippians 2:14).

Addendum: If Jesus *was* God, it doesn't make sense to say he could or could not 'grasp at' equality *with* God. If Jesus is God, he simply is equal to God in all respects. The sentence just doesn't make sense on a trinitarian reading.

Comment: ty for your answer. I'm puzzled by how you place Jesus with God but not God. John 1:1-3 says *nothing* about Jesus or a son on purpose. Who is this Jesus with God? He is not an angel (as some strangely insist) There is no 'God the Son', there is no son until Jesus who is holy and has divine attributes.

Comment: @user48152 Your comment is a bit cryptic to me, so forgive me if I misunderstand it. 'Jesus' is a name given to a baby who is the incarnation of the Logos. So by reference, we can say 'Jesus' = the Logos = 'Christ Jesus'. I never said that Jesus is 'God the Son' - as you rightly point out, that isn't a Biblical term. Rather, Jesus is the 'Son of God'.

Comment: Ahh, I get you now. Pls see link for another take on logos. I believe that John is telling us *what* the logos is not *who*. If not a *who*, there is no incarnation - which is not a biblical concept either. :) https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47927/who-is-the-word-in-john-11/47942?r=SearchResults&s=7|17.7142#47942

Comment: @user48152 Ya, that's an interesting idea ... I don't reflexively reject it, but as is obvious I have no problem with thinking John is identifying the Logos with Jesus.

Comment: Of course he is... when Jesus was conceived and born @~4BC and of course as planned from the beginning Heb 1:2 - careful - it is, made the 'ages' not *world*. And as you point out, Jesus is, the *representation* of His (God's) nature

Answer (score 1):

> Phl 2:3-9 KJV - 3 [Let] nothing [be done] through strife or vainglory;
> but in lowliness of mind let each esteem other better than themselves.
> 4 Look not every man on his own things, but every man also on the
> things of others. 5  Let this mind be in you, which was also in Christ
> Jesus: 6 Who, being in the form of God, thought it not robbery to be
> equal with God: 7 But made himself of no reputation, and took upon him
> the form of a servant, and was made in the likeness of men: 8 And
> being found in fashion as a man, he humbled himself, and became
> obedient unto death, even the death of the cross. 9 Wherefore God also
> hath highly exalted him, and given him a name which is above every
> name:

1. The passage speaks of our learning humility from Christ
2. The passage states that Christ was "in the form of God"
3. It tells us that despite His being "in the form of God", He "took upon him the form of a servant"

We learn here of Jesus, Who being in God's form, and equal with God - as it was not robbery for Him to claim equality with God - as He did on many occasions causing the Jews to try and stone Him - humbled himself.

Taking the passage in context, we have Jesus, the One Who is equal with God (Is 9:6), as manifest by His not considering it thievery to claim that equality, setting us an example of humility by the way He humbled Himself in coming to earth for us.

Answer (score 1):

First let us have a direct literal translation of Phlp 2:5-8:

> [5] τουτο γαρ φρονεισθω εν υμιν ο και εν χριστω ιησου [6] ος εν μορφη θεου υπαρχων ουχ αρπαγμον ηγησατο το ειναι ισα θεω [7] αλλ εαυτον εκενωσεν μορφην δουλου λαβων εν ομοιωματι ανθρωπων γενομενος [8] και σχηματι ευρεθεις ως ανθρωπος εταπεινωσεν εαυτον γενομενος υπηκοος μεχρι θανατου θανατου δε σταυρου
> [5] For let this be regarded in you, that also [was regarded] in Christ Jesus [6] who, being in [the] form of God, did not consider being just like God [to be] robbery [7] but emptied himself, having taken [the] form of [a] slave, having come to be in [the] likeness of men. [8] And having been found [in] fashion as [a] man, [he] brought himself low, having come to be obedient even until death, moreover death of [a] cross.

Why did I choose to render "μορφη θεου" as "form of God" rather than "of [a] god" to match the parallel with "form of [a] man" later? Well, I felt that the "ισα θεω" did not make sense with an indefinite "θεω", so it should refer to (the true) God, in which case "μορφη θεου" should also refer to the form of God, since it is common to see the definite article dropped from "θεου" when modifying indefinite nouns like the "μορφη" here.

And why did I choose to render "ισα θεω" as "just like God" rather than "equal to God"? You may be surprised that this one is completely straightforward; "equal to God" in standard English may mean "identical to God" or "an equal to God". But neither of these are possible here! "ισα" is **neuter**, not masculine, so it cannot refer to Jesus himself! So "ισα θεω" here simply means "just like God" and nothing more, namely similarity in an abstract sense, just like in Luke 6:34 and LXX Job 10:10, 11:12, 24:20, Isa 51:23. If the author wanted to say "an equal to God", he should use "ισος" (masculine) instead as in John 5:18.

And why "robbery"? I did not find clear evidence that "αρπαγμος" can mean "a thing to be seized", so I went with the default "act of robbing" as per [LSJ](https://lsj.gr/wiki/%E1%BC%81%CF%81%CF%80%CE%B1%CE%B3%CE%BC%CF%8C%CF%82). Observe that the second meaning offered by LSJ is based on no evidence at all, because they cited Phlp 2:6 (which sheds no light) and also referred to a different word "αρπαγμα". Note that if related nouns are formed from the same root verb via different declensions, generally the "-ς" declension refers to the action itself, whereas the "-α" declensions refer to the result or abstract concept related to the verb. For instance compare "κρισις" (act of judging) and "κριμα" (judgement). So looking at the meaning of "αρπαγμα" provides no evidence for "αρπαγμος" meaning "object of robbing".

So, what does Phlp 2:5-8 mean as a whole? Clearly your question about what "exploited" means is not even the right question, since the text itself *definitely* does not have anything to do with "exploitation"! In simple English, I would say it means:

> For you should keep this in mind, that also Christ Jesus kept in mind (who existed in the same form as God and so did not think that being just like God was robbery, but discarded that form and took the form of a slave and came in the likeness of a man): He was found to be living in the fashion of a man, and brought himself low by being obedient even until death, death of a cross.

To explain, Phlp 2:5-8 says that, since Jesus existed in the same form as God, he would of course not consider being just like God as a robbery, because he never took what he already had. That said, he discarded that likeness with God that he had and took instead the form of a slave, the likeness of a man, living in the fashion of a man, being obedient as if he was a lowly slave.

Comment: In short: you conclude that Jesus pre-existed his physical incarnation and was **like** God, i.e. he had divine attributes, but he was not necessarily 100% **equal** to God, correct? Are there divine attributes that God has but Jesus doesn't?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator: Absolutely correct; that is what the texts literally imply, and consistently so throughout all the writings in the Protestant canon. For your second inquiry, there are certainly some clear-cut attributes on which Jesus and God differ: (1) God is not a man but Jesus is a man; (2) God is the source, but Jesus is not the source. But are those "divine attributes"? Maybe you won't consider them so. If you're asking about "divine nature" or something like that, then yes I would say that Jesus has exactly the same divine nature as God.

Comment: What do you mean God is the source but Jesus isn't? How do you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator: As I stated in [this comment](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/112291), Jesus explicitly says that he went forth from God, but not from himself. This directly implies that God is the source but he is not. Of course, this verse alone does not tell you everything about God being the source of everything; for that you have to look elsewhere. But at least it is clear enough that God is the source of Jesus in the specific sense that Jesus stated in John 8:42, and Jesus is not his own source in that sense.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator: By the way, I cannot understand why you accepted RevelationLad's post at the other thread, given the indisputable errors he/she made all over especially in comments on my post. Even the "postscript" is just 100% circular! Of course if Jesus was a trinitarian he would say funny things; that is the natural consequence of being a trinitarian. But in reality Jesus was not a trinitarian...

Comment: Feel free to post rebuttal comments below @RevelationLad's answer and I might end up changing my mind. So far his/her answer has received 0 rebuttals.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator: Ah I see. I avoided commenting on most other posts there mainly because I didn't want to explicitly post rebuttals that my answer implicitly covered. Please give me a few minutes to state my thoughts on that post explicitly.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator: Did you see my objections to the post you accepted? As usual, trinitarians cannot deny my objections but always bring up many other unrelated verses that they twist to 'support' their theology. Note that RevelationLad also did not respond to my objection, but merely changed the last sentence to a kind of weasel phrasing, since "as the Jews understood" may mean either "as the Jews correctly understood" or "as the Jews believed", which are very different. As you can see from all the comment threads, no trinitarian actually wants to face the real facts I brought up...

Comment: If think you guys pretty much agree with each other, except for "ontological" details. You already said that for all practical purposes Jesus is as "Godlike" as his Father, in the sense that he has the same divine nature. This is the same claim that trinitarians make as far as I'm aware. The only difference appears to be in the technicalities of the ontological nature of Jesus. Some claim that Jesus and the Father are ontologically the same entity. Others claim that they are ontologically independent entities. Others believe they are different manifestations of a same entity, etc.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator: I don't think that's an accurate description. If you take an actual look at the (pagan) history of trinitarianism, and their politics-driven silencing of opposing views (not that I buy any one opposing view) in the 3rd century, you will probably come to a more accurate understanding of what is going on here. It is not just about ontology; for some inexplicable reason the trinitarians **want** Jesus to be **fully the one true God** including even being Origin and Creator and having the highest authority. All that is contradicted very clearly by the writings.

Comment: In your opinion, what would you say are the 3 most notable passages that discredit the trinity?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator: I would say John 8:17-18,42 and 1 Cor 15:24-28 are good candidates, but I think there are many others that I cannot recall at the moment.

Comment: I hope this question gives you more tribune to develop your argument: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/55872/is-the-son-second-in-authority-under-god-the-father-1-corinthians-1524-28

Answer (score 0):

English Standard Version

> who, though he was in the form of God, did not count equality with God a thing to be **grasped**,

Thayer's Greek Lexicon

> STRONGS NT 725: ἁρπαγμός
>
> 1. the act of **seizing**, robbery (so Plutarch, de book educ. c. 15 (others 14, 37), vol. 2:12 a. the only instance of its use noted in secular authors).
> 2. a thing seized or to be seized, booty: ἁρπαγμόν ἡγεῖσθαι τί to deem anything a prlze — a thing to be seized upon or to be held fast, retained,

In https://biblehub.com/parallel/philippians/2-6.htm, 16 versions translate the Greek word as "grasped". Only one translates it as "exploited".

Equality with God is God. It is a self-identity, a tautology. As such, God cannot be exploited by anyone.

The context shows Jesus' humility. Jesus did not seize upon this equality.
The passage is not about anyone exploiting the equality of God. On the contrary, it is about
Matthew 23:12

> For those who exalt themselves will be humbled, and those who humble themselves will be exalted.

Comment: "Equality with God is God. It is a self-identity, a tautology." Then why does Paul talk about Jesus, then God, then equality? Wouldn't it be more straightforward for Paul to simply note an identity, instead of a strange phrase like 'in the form of God'?

Comment: That's part of the mystery of the Trinity which is beyond my understanding. So my humble answer is: I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus had equality with God which he did not exploit (used for his own benefit) but which he did empty by serving others. He"***came to serve not to be served***"(Mark 10:45). That is, He used his equality with God for the benefit of others.

> Philippians 2:5-8 (NRSV):
>
> 5 Let the same mind be in you that was in Christ Jesus, 6 who, though he was in the form of God, did not regard ***equality with God*** as something to be ***exploited***, 7 but ***emptied himself***, taking ***the form of a slave***, being born in human likeness. And being found in human form, 8 he humbled himself and became obedient to the point of death— even death on a cross.

"Equality with God" was something Jesus did not "exploit" (i.e. did not use for his own advantage or benefit). When Christ had fasted for forty days and forty nights in the wilderness, Satan tempted him and told him to "***turn the stone into bread***" but Jesus refused because he did not want to use his equality with God for his own benefit (Matthew 4:1). In the wedding at Cana, Jesus "***turned water into wine***" using his divine power and that benefitted other people (John 2:8).

Therefore, Jesus was equal with God the Father in regard to being able to do miracles.

Comment: Jesus said 'he could do nothing of himself' - not that he wouldn't. He couldn't. If he was God then he wasn't 'made like us in every way'. Heb 2:17 We are not equal to God - neither was he. You have misunderstood John 5:19 it refers to *what* Jesus did, not how he did it. And what he said John 12:49. Even in Rev Jesus still has the same God as us, 1:1 God is still giving him what he needs.

Comment: +1 for giving a specific answer to what 'equality' might consist of - the ability to do miracles. I agree with @user48152 that the text is a bit problematic at John 5:19 for a claim to 'equality'.

Comment: @Anthony Burg, I removed the part where I included John 5:19. I realised it is already discussing another verse unrelated to your question. I was referring to Jesus who was claiming to be equal with God in John 5:18. I guess a new question of why is it that calling God his own father means he's claiming to be equal with God in John 5:18. God is indeed our father (Malachi 2:10) but here in John 5:18 Jesus is singled out as equal with God just because he calls God his father.

Answer (score -1):

Jesus' equality with God Philippians 2:6 seems to me that he was in the form of God. Being equal to God is as in St.John 1:1 is God," The Word was with God and the Word was God" This equality is that he emptied himself this seems to be more on the emotional state of being that is his literal removal of powers or God's ability.
For instance, one can humble themselves and still have ability/power and authority. Therefore I render the usage he did not count his equality with God as something to be used for his advantage. This is corralative to the text because it says he humbled himself and being humble doesn't necessarily entail the absence of ability or strength. Notice also in the Gospels it is noted Christ jas all power and Authority. This is granted before his crucifixion as I believe he came into the world with it. Yet did not use his God status or allow his Divine nature to immediately allow punishment. Anyone who desecrated the Ark of the Covenant died
such as Uzai. Yet Christ Greater than the ark was ridiculed beaten spat on and mocked. This humbling and guard of mercy held back divine judgment. And was not a judgment at his disposal! Yeah, the scripture says that he started All judgment has been committed unto the Son for the Father himself judges no one. Jesus also told Peter at his arrest he could call upon the Father to dispatch twelve legions of angels and it would be granted at once. So then the act of humility isn't a discarding of his ability as God. Rather a restraining from usage and tying of self to the degree of obedience to the Father and his desire. This is the mind to have in Christ that humility as lowering ourselves to serve others. Notice that Christ is therefore exalted after the resurrection. That he has all power and Authority yet he'd already stated this before the crucifixion. So then his exaltation is moving from a lowly state of corrupt able flesh to a higher state of physical divinity for a sport doth not have flesh and bone as you see me. Thomas answered and said, My Lord and My God.

Jesus' mindset was to be humble and save the world because the world was condemned already and didn't believe in him. The whole humility was a divine act of ultimate grace.